# Comment delete limit

Tags: discussion, comments, rate-limiting, deleted-comments

Are there any restrictions for comment's if I delete my own comments many times?
After deleting some my own question, I've found that I was permanently blocked from asking question.
Is it gonna happen for comments too?

Comment: Nope, comments are not subject to an automatic ban.

Comment: Though, if we find people abusing comments, we might have to add such a ban.

Comment: @Oded: Trust me, you eventually will.

Comment: @Oded I delete a lot of my own comments, so am interested in what ways you feel this may be involved with abusing comments. How would deleting comments be abused?

Comment: @BillWoodger - My thoughts are more towards people **writing** abusive/spammish comments. I can't see deletion of comments ever being a problem (given that we see comments as ephemeral).

Comment: @Oded thanks. I think I had an implicit "deleting" along with Martijn's comment, due to the question, so got confused.

Comment: @BillWoodger consider someone who post offensive comment, let it stay for short time only until the post author see it, then delete. When author reply back he says "what? I didn't write any offensive comment". Do it lots of times, and this is abusing the system.

Comment: @Oded since deleting a comment is treated as a vote, isn't it limited to 30 as well?

Comment: @ShadowWizard - not sure that it counts as a vote or that it is subject to vote limits.

Comment: @LowerClassOverflowian many users, even veterans, are not aware of that so they'll just leave it, frustrated. There is no mechanism to view last deleted comments (like 10k users have for deleted posts) and no auto flag raised in such case.

Comment: @Oded true, just cleaned up over 30 comments to be sure. Anyway, post ban happens if you delete **downvoted** posts of yours and since there are no downvotes for comments, it's not relevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will not be banned from your comment privileges for deleting many of your comments. There is no comment delete limit.